# Visual Studio 2010 managed c++ targets .NET 2.0 PROBLEM

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0, 64-bit, c++-cli

For someone who's been down this road, please share your breadcrumbs.

I have old VS2005 solution.  Most of the parts are c# but I have one c++ managed project.  Dev machine: Windows XP.  Target framework version: 2.0

I moved the project to the Windows 7 64 BIT, VS 2010, did the project conversion.  First thing I noticed were build errors - projects depending on one what is in c++ complained that project referenced has target 4.0 and I want to use it in project that (properly) targets 2.0.

OK, so I used some tips and set my project target to .NET 2.0.  NOW: VS2010 complains that it cannot load the project because I need to install framework 2.0.  OK, so I try to install it, and nothing - since installer detects .NET 2.0 as a part of the operating system.

WTF?

Admins, please create WTF tag for me here :)

Comment: +1 for WTF tag (sorry for spam...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not the .NET version that's the problem.  The C++ build system currently does not directly support building for pre-.NET 4.0 targets.  It requires VS2008 to be installed so it can use its tool chain.  Sounds like you don't have it.

This [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/framework-multi-targeting-for-vc-projects/) explains the workaround.  You can upvote this [feedback article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/567504/targeting-frameworks-other-than-4-0-with-c-cli-project-and-v100-platform-toolset) if you're unhappy with that.  No idea if this is slated to be fixed in SP1, this is not drawing a lot of votes.

Comment: It seems like I am goona install VS2005 and stay low on Windows 7x64.  Microsoft has its ways of phasing out old tech.

Comment: I'll accept this, because I got info I needed - AVOID vs 2010 until .net40 ready.